# How to get info about all running activities in android programmatically?

Tags: android

In android, you get info about running activities by watching the Logcat.

For example if you open camera, it is logged in the Logcat.

Is there a way to get that info programmatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList =  m.getRunningTasks(10);
    Iterator<RunningTaskInfo> itr = runningTaskInfoList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo = (RunningTaskInfo)itr.next();
        int id = runningTaskInfo.id;
        CharSequence desc= runningTaskInfo.description;
        String topActivity = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getShortClassName();
        int numOfActivities = runningTaskInfo.numActivities;
    }
```

**Note:** You have to specify `android.permission.GET_TASKS` permission in Manifest file.

Comment: This method is deprecated with Lolipop, because of its shift towards document centric task management, which could leak personal information.