# Android : get timing information of running application

Tags: android

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736680/how-to-get-info-about-all-running-activities-in-android) code to get information of currently running applications in android app.
I want to how I can get timing information(start time) of currently running applications

Comment: Haven't found any method to get this info for all applications, but it's very easy to keep track of when your own applications were started. I'm guessing that doesn't really help you though.

Comment: I am finding solution for getting start-time for all applications.

Comment: You can check ActiviyManager's log in Logcat when activity is started and can extract pgrommatically the log time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 long millisSinceBoot = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
         System.out.println("00000    "+millisSinceBoot);
         System.out.println("11111    "+values.get(position).activeSince+" "+values.get(position).process);
         long time = ((millisSinceBoot - values.get(position).activeSince)/1000);
         int[] vals = splitToComponentTimes(time);

         String time1 = vals[0]+":"+vals[1]+":"+vals[2];
         time_list.add(time);        
         timer.setText(time1);

         System.out.println("valssssss "+vals[0]+" "+vals[1]);
```